# Modify hex value position using C++

Tags: c++, hex

I've got an executable and I want to move a hex value. That hex value is a key for decryption so I need to move it down for safety.

C++ Code:

```
static DWORD s_adwEterPackKey[] =
{
    45129401,
    92367215,
    681285731,
    1710201,
};
```

Hex Value:

```
¹ž°.oi..c˜›(y...
```

When someone searches for a text like "AVCEterPackManager" with HxD would be able to find the key, so I must move it down. Here is a picture with the actual hex:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean "move down"? Are you trying to obscure the key? Keep in mind that security through obscurity will ultimately be broken

Comment: It is possible to modify any memory location as long as the memory is within the scope of the executable.  It may be hard to find exact location since code is not loaded as absolute locations.  An Executable is loaded on the execution stack by the loader when the application is started.

Comment: Hmm you are right but is not a esential code is just a key that why i want to move it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be trivial to extract the key from a binary if you store it unencrypted no matter where it is placed in the binary.

Instead of implementing very weak crypto (in your case obviously just "[security by obsurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity)") yourself, you should definitely better use a library to do that job. There are plenty of algorithms and implementations available that would encrypt your data in a secure fashion.